# why does the size of docker images vary on different systems

Tags: docker

On my laptop I have an image which is 2.34GB.

Uploaded to gitlab registry it is 929MB.

And when I try to pull it to my server which has 7GB space I run out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Docker images are conformed by layers. 
So, if you deploy an image on a computer that already has some layers of image you're deploying, its size is lower.
When you deploy from the registry, where are compressed, size is bigger.

Comment: Isnt the size reported by docker images supposed to be the total size for the container including all layers?

Comment: And what happened with the pull where I had 7GB of space? I have just rerun it and it worked, still leaving 5GB of free space. I guess there was some disk space that was reported as free by linux but still being cleaned up so not yet available.

Comment: When you say that in your laptop have 2.34Gb and in your server 7Gb, both places do you have the same number of images? Does `docker images` show you the same? I don't think so. Are you sure that you're checking docker images and not docker containers? Containers are used to being bigger because inside Dockerfile you can do installations which occupates more space.

Comment: @simon: If you are using btrfs as your filesystem with Docker, it can give very confusing reports about disk space. Since it is copy on write, and Docker uses snapshot subvolumes to save space, writing into a new layer can suddenly use more space than you expect. There are other things too, like autodefrag suddenly unsharing megabytes of CoW data.

Comment: The server had 7GB total free space via linux df command. The image is only 2.34GB. So I figured to download a compressed version and decompress it there would only be a need for 5GB. Yet  it failed. 20 minutes later tried again and it worked.